# Weak and strong properties in -viewDidUnload under ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to iphone development . I am using ARC for my project. As far as I understood using ARC we don't have to release any object manually. But , I have observed in some places , people explicitly set their object to nil in the ViewDidUnload even after using ARC.

For example, in .h file I have something like this:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapViewOutlet;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

And .m as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
     [self setMapViewOutlet:nil];
     [self setToolBar:nil];
     [super viewDidUnload];
     self.dataArray=nil;
}
```

My question is, is it really necessary to explicitly specify nil in the ViewDidUnload even under ARC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole point of the `viewDidUnload` method is to release data that you don’t really need, in order to free memory. Read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s
>   views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from
>   memory. This method is called after the view controller’s view has
>   been released and is your chance to perform any final cleanup. If your
>   view controller stores separate references to the view or its
>   subviews, you should use this method to release those references. You
>   can also use this method to remove references to any objects that you
>   created to support the view but that are no longer needed now that the
>   view is gone. You should not use this method to release user data or
>   any other information that cannot be easily recreated.

So you’re setting the properties to `nil` in order to release the objects *now* and help the system to free up some memory. But of course this depends on the property type – strong properties are “yours” and only you can decide whether to release them now (by setting to `nil`) or not. Weak properties could already be `nil`, for example if they pointed to some views that got released with the main view. And `unsafe_unretained` properties are a special beast. The object they point to might already been released, but that does not mean they were set to `nil` automatically. So you should either use one of the “safer” property types (strong/weak), or set the unsafe properties to `nil` here, to make sure you won’t use the released object later. There are no hard rules in this case, you have to think about the situation and what it means for the various properties.

By the way, `viewDidUnload` is getting deprecated in iOS 6, where no views are being released under low-memory conditions anymore. You still receive the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` callback, so that you can release some resources there if you want to. Again, I suggest that you read the documentation and run a few tests to see what happens and decide what you should do.

Comment: But, even if I don't set to nil , the system will free up the memory automatically in ARC right ?

Comment: Eventually, yes. It’s hard(er) to create a leak under ARC. It’s up to you to decide if you can help the system by freeing some big chunk of memory when your app receives the memory warning.

Comment: I got one more doubt.Strong properties are never released automatically in ARC? If I dont set it to nil explicitly , it is never released ?

Comment: They are, in `dealloc`. As I said, it’s hard to create a leak just by omission under ARC.

Comment: Sorry sorry . This thing really confused me now .That means we explicitly dont have it to be set to nil, when we are using strong property ?I assume , it is not right method to set strong property to nil explicitly , instead ARC will automatically call the dealloc for the strong properties.

Comment: You’re trying to grasp too many things at once. There are two things in play here – the overall memory management of strong properties *and* the situation when system is low on memory and tries to free some in coordination with the apps. Overall, you don’t have to release strong properties manually by setting them to `nil`, ARC will take care of that. *But* if you know the system is low on memory and want to help, you can manually release strong properties that you don’t need at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zoul:). Your explanation was really good . Now I got the difference :)

Answer (score 3):

ARC will only release properties which do not hold a strong reference to an object. In your case, these are all strong references, so they will be kept unless they are explicitly set to nil.

The `viewDidUnload` method does not mean that your `UIViewController` is removed from memory, it simply means that its views are removed from memory ([iOS Developer - ViewController lifecycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW1)).

In this case, your `UIViewController` remains in memory, and therefore its properties as well, unless they are explicitly set to nil.

Comment: In my case, they are not all strong references. For your info, weak is not supported in IOS4 , instead we use unsafe-unretained, which may some time create dangling pointers . The functionality wise both are same

Comment: Correct, sorry I was looking for the weak keyword (now only developing for iOS5).

Comment: and as far as I know ARC will automatically call dealloc for the strong references.Hence we don't have to set them to nil explicitly.Where as for the weak references we are setting it to nil,in order to avoid dangling pointers which may be possible in some cases

Comment: Weak properties exist precisely in order to avoid dangling pointers. When the object being pointed to by a weak property is deallocated, the weak property is set to `nil` automatically.

Comment: yea , but unsafe_unretained ( which is a a replacement to weak in ios 4) may create dangling pointers . Hence we have to set them to nil explicitly.this is what I understood as of now. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using unsafe_unretained, you should assign it to nil because it will not be assigned to nil implicitly, where is case of weak reference it will be assigned to nil implicitly.So in order to avoid any dangling reference you need to assign to nil in case of unsafe_unretained.

Comment: Yea even I thought the same . But I have seen in some places even the weak references set to nil .In my question you can see even the strong reference set to nil.