# In XCode 4.6.2, why does creating an outlet on a UITextView auto-generate a viewDidUnload method

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, viewdidunload

I have a simple "About" view that I've made in a storyboard.  Basically all it has is a `UITextView`.  It's controller looks like this:

```
// AboutViewController.m

#import "AboutViewController.h"

@interface AboutViewController()

@end

@implementation AboutViewController

@end
```

I want to add an outlet for the UITextView so I can add some rounded corners in code.  When I `Ctrl` + drag from the storyboard up in between the `@interface` and `@end` and call the outlet *aboutBlurb*, my `AboutViewController.m` becomes the following:

```
// AboutViewController.m
#import "AboutViewController.h"

@interface AboutViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *aboutBlurb;

@end

@implementation AboutViewController

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setAboutBlurb:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

My question is, why is XCode inserting the `viewDidUnload` method and `nil`ing my `aboutBlurb` property?  I thought with ARC, `nil`ing properties in the `viewDidUnload` method was unnecessary.  Furthermore, I thought Apple had deprecated the `viewDidUnload` method completely in iOS 6.  Is there a rational reason for the `viewDidUnload` method being auto-generated, or can I safely remove it?

Comment: that's because your Development Target is iOS5 or below, and in the versions previous to iOS6 the implementation of this method is recommended

Comment: @tkanzakic am I right that under ARC the call to `[self setAboutBlurb:nil]` is superfluous though, or have I misunderstood how ARC works?

Comment: that could depend in the IBOutlet declaration, but in your case that you declare it as `weak` I think it is not necessary, take look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12104705/1411844

Comment: @BryceThomas: if it was not superfluous in MRC then it is not superfluous in ARC